# Use \def without including the square bracktes with pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots

I would like to define a line style to use in my pictures.

But would still like to retain the flexibility to be able to tweak these if needed in the actual picture, as in the third picture (commented out) below. But can't seem to get this to work. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the `\def`s have a comma separated list in them, but then again the second picture has no problems.. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\LineStyleWithSqBrackets{[green, thick]}
\def\LineStyleWithoutSqBrackets{green, thick}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \draw [green, thick] (0,0) circle (7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \draw \LineStyleWithSqBrackets   (0,0) circle (7);
\end{tikzpicture}

%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
%   \draw [\LineStyleWithoutSqBrackets]   (0,0) circle (7);
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of the possibility to define "real" styles using `\tikzstyle{<name>}=[<keys>]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{linestyle}=[green,thick]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
   \draw [linestyle]   (0,0) circle (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While the `\tikzstyle` macro is used in the examples of the `pgfmanual` it is never officially documented. No idea why. The "official" syntax is `\tikzset{<name>/.style={<style>}}` like `\tikzset{linestyle/.style={green,thick},otherstyle/.style={...}`.

Comment: This works great. It is even possible to append to the linestyle using: `\draw [linestyle, dashed]   (0,0) circle (7);` so this does everything I needed.

Comment: The \tikzstyle is the "pre PGF 2.00" way of defining options. Seems its documentation has been discarded (accidentally?) when the new pgfkeys feature has been documented for PGF 2.00.

Comment: @Martin: Would you mind turning your comment into an answer, so that can be accepted instead of mine?

Answer (score 4):

Jake's answer is definitely the way to go.  What's going wrong with your method is that the macro containing the options is being expanded at (for you) the wrong time.  When the macro has the square brackets within it, then TeX expands the macro once to see what it is, sees the square brackets, and realises that this is the options for the draw command.  So that works as it should.  But in the second version, when you put the square brackets in explicitly, then TeX doesn't have to expand the macro to find them.  It then passes the macro *unexpanded* to the machinery that figures out the options.  This divides up the options *before* expanding them, so the macro gets considered as a *single* option of "green, thick" rather than as two options.  From this point on, chaos ensues!

TikZ's own method of appending options and defining styles is designed knowing how the processing works, so Jake's solution is that of working *with* the system rather than trying to work around it.